# why is navigation stuck on Loading on logging in to the react native Expo application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, expo

My application is stuck on loading Screen after providing successful login credentials.
I think when i navigate to Loading from AppNavigator, useEffect does not work on AuthLoadingScreen.

**App Flow**

- *AuthScreen* navigates to *AuthLoadingScreen*.
- *AuthLoadingScreen* verifies the Access Token from the AsyncStorage and if the token is valid, it should navigate to *'Main'* which is the dashboard of the application. Hence it's stuck on loading as you can see in the screenshot [Simulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD7oO.png)

**AppNavigator.js**

```jsx
function AppNavigator() {
  
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Loading'>
          <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthScreen} options={{headerShown: false}} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={SignupScreen} options={{headerShown: false}} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={App} options={{headerShown: false}} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Loading" component={AuthLoadingScreen} options={{headerShown: true}}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
  
  export default AppNavigator;
```

**AuthScreen.js**

```jsx
 performLogin = (email, password, successCb, errorCb) => {
    const successCallback = (response) => {
      successCb();
      this.setState({
        tabIndex: 0
      });
      
      const decodedToken = jwtDecoder(response.access);
      const decodedTokenRefresh = jwtDecoder(response.refresh);
      AsyncStorage.setItem('@tabir-graphql:session', JSON.stringify({
        token: response.access,
        tokenRefresh: response.refresh,
        name: response.user,
        id: decodedToken.user_id,
        exp: decodedToken.exp,
        expRefresh: decodedTokenRefresh.exp
      })).then(() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Loading'); // navigate to Loading Screen
      })
    }
    login(email, password, successCallback, errorCb);
  }
```

**AuthLoadingScreen.js**

```jsx
const AuthLoadingScreen = ({ navigation }) =>  {
 // auth init function
  const _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    // Fetch token from storage
    const session = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@tabir-graphql:session');
    // If session exists, validate it, else redirect to login screen
    if (session) {
      const sessionObj = JSON.parse(session);
      var currentTime = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
      if (currentTime < sessionObj.exp) {
        console.log(sessionObj.exp - currentTime);
        setLogout(() => navigation.navigate('Auth'));
        navigation.navigate('Main');
      }
      else {
        navigation.navigate('Auth');
      }
    } else {
      navigation.navigate('Auth');
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    _bootstrapAsync();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <CenterSpinner />
    </View>
  );
```

Comment: try wrapping `try catch` to `_bootstrapAsync()`. I think something is throwing error there hence its not navigating anywhere

Comment: @jted95 Actually useEffect does not work when the AuthLoadingScreen is opened.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Is there any error you got in the log?

Comment: @jted95 Actually what i did was, i put console.log inside useEffect hook but console.log never prints anything on logging in but once i reload the application, it's working fine